# plugin is removed on android app on build

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, pushwoosh

I'm trying to integrate push notifications using the pushwoosh plugin. I installed the plugin using the command line:

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin.git
```

and in config.xml:

```
<access origin="*.pushwoosh.com" />
```

and added the javascript code for `initPushwoosh()` and the rest of the code.
Then when I build the app successfully
I found that pushwoosh plugin and some code from config.xml is removed automatically.
The push notification also does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2012/12/04/easy-phonegap-push-notifications-with-pushwoosh/) and see what you have missed

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are editing the files in the correct "www" folder. There could be more than one "www" folders and one could override another when you make a build.